# How to populate weeks number based on date occurance in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a data like below:

```
************************************************************************************************

                                                    May - 2020


                    Date                                          Week                 Week Count

Fri May 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)             18                   1   
Sat May 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)             18                   1   
Sun May 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)             18                   1+2 = 3  
Mon May 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              19                  1
Tue May 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              19                  1
Wed May 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              19                  1
Thu May 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              19                  1
Fri May 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              19                  1
Sat May 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              19                  1
Sun May 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              19                  1+6 = 7
Mon May 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              20                  1
Tue May 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              20                  1
Wed May 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              20                  1
Thu May 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              20                  1
Fri May 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              20                  1
Sat May 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              20                  1
Sun May 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              20                  1+6 = 7
Mon May 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              21                  1
Tue May 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              21                  1
Wed May 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              21                  1
Thu May 21 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              21                  1
Fri May 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              21                  1
Sat May 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              21                  1
Sun May 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              21                  1+6 = 7 
Mon May 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              22                  1
Tue May 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              22                  1
Wed May 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              22                  1
Thu May 28 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              22                  1
Fri May 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              22                  1
Sat May 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              22                  1
Sun May 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)              22                  1+6 = 7

***********************************************************************************************
```

And I like to arrange it like based on week occurances:
So final result will be like:

```
18=>3, 19=>7, 20=> 7, 21=>7, 22=>7
```

So in May, 18th week occured 1 time but 3 dates were occupied in `18th week of may 2020.
Similarly, same goes for other dates in stated above

The code I am trying is:

```js
{
  daysNumber.map((number, index) => {
    let d = number.split('-');
    NDate = new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2]);
    weekNum = this.getWeekNumber(NDate);
  })
}

getWeekNumber(now) {
  let onejan = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  return Math.ceil((((now - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()) / 7);
}

getDaysNumber(year, month) {
        const dates = [];
        const daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
        for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
            let parts = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + i);
            dates.push(this.convertToDesiredDate(parts));
        }
        return dates;
    }

convertToDesiredDate(str) {
        let date = new Date(str),
            month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
            day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        return [date.getFullYear(), month, day].join("-");
    }
```

Where daysNumber contains the month days starting from 01-31 ( for may ).

It will grow depends on the month.

I am stuck at populating them as an array to find how many times a week appeared in dates like my output.

Comment: I am sorry, the data is coming for dates loop. My intention is to show weeks and weeks number on dates. So on my UI from date 1 2 3 i will week 18 of may was in these 3 dates. did you get it now?

Comment: getWeekNumber is js function and it takes date and tell me the calendar month of that date.

Comment: I am sorry about that mistake!!

Comment: WHat is the input? What is `number` that you split on dash?

Comment: its basically string based date like: `2020-05-01`,  `2020-05-02` up to  `2020-05-31`

Comment: Removed the react tag :)

Comment: Is this the question you want to fix the week numbers on?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Need to fix week numbers here. :)

Comment: I am investigating luxon but am stuck on something

Comment: Oh no issue but how about doing it with Momentjs?

Comment: Luxon is newer..

Comment: I added a version with Luxon AND moment

Comment: Let me review it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/tour.html)

```
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;    
const weekNums = days.reduce((obj, dateString) => {
  let d = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(dateString))
  const week = d.weekNumber;
  console.log(d,d.weekdayLong,week)
  obj[week] = (obj[week] + 1) || 1;
  return obj;
}, {})
```

```js
const days = `Fri May 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 21 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 28 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)`.split("\n")

// https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/tour.html#parse-from-iso-8601
// https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js~DateTime.html
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const weekNums = days.reduce((obj, dateString) => {
  let d = DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(dateString))
  const week = d.weekNumber;
  console.log(d,d.weekdayLong,week)
  obj[week] = (obj[week] + 1) || 1;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(weekNums)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.24.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Using moment

```
const weekNums = days.reduce((obj, dateString) => {
  let d = moment(dateString)
  const week = d.isoWeek();
  console.log(week,d.format('dddd'))
  obj[week] = (obj[week] + 1) || 1;
  return obj;
}, {})
```

```js
const days = `Fri May 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 21 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 28 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)`.split("\n")

const weekNums = days.reduce((obj, dateString) => {
  let d = moment(dateString)
  const week = d.isoWeek();
  console.log(week,d.format('dddd'))
  obj[week] = (obj[week] + 1) || 1;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(weekNums)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/locale/de.min.js"></script>
```

**OLD ANSWER:**

Using the elegant [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const weekNums = days.reduce((obj,dateString) => {
  const week = getWeekNumber(new Date(dateString));
  obj[week] = (obj[week]+1) || 1;
  return obj; 
},{})
```

PS: Week numbers start on the week that has the first thursday in the year

```js
const days = `Fri May 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 02 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 03 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 04 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 05 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 07 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 08 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 09 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 10 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 12 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 13 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 14 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 15 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 16 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 17 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 18 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 19 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 21 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 22 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 23 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 24 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Mon May 25 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Tue May 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Wed May 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Thu May 28 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Fri May 29 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sat May 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
Sun May 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)`.split("\n")



const getWeekNumber = now => {
  let onejan = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  return Math.ceil((((now - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()) / 7);
}

const getDaysNumber = (year, month) => {
  const dates = [];
  const daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
  for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
    let parts = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + i);
    dates.push(this.convertToDesiredDate(parts));
  }
  return dates;
}

const weekNums = days.reduce((obj, dateString) => {
  const week = getWeekNumber(new Date(dateString));
  obj[week] = (obj[week] + 1) || 1;
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(weekNums)
```

Comment: Thats very close but see in may 2020, 1st to 3rd there are 3 days makes one week that is 18th week of calendar 2020. Similarly, for other dates it split up in 7 days based on dates. Like 4th - 10th ( 2nd week but 19th week of calandar ) n it will goes up to 31st May.

Comment: Also I need to see how many dates did 18th week has, similarly, how many dates did 19th week has, and up to 31st.

Comment: Ok Sorry ;). See, May started from 1st may friday and from friday to sunday there are 3 days in it so 1st week of may contains only 3 days. Caledar month says there are 3 dates in 18th week of 2020. So 18=>3

Comment: Next monday (4th) to sun (10th) - 7 days in 2nd week of may but its 19th week of calendar 2020. So in 19th week of 2020 there are 7 days so 19=>7

Comment: That it :) Thanks a lot. I will test it in my code base and come up with query if left any. I am accepting your answer. Sorry about my poor understanding.

Comment: A reduce is more elegant. You can do in in one go. I'll try it now

Comment: Yes, I am also reading it and that's make more sense. Its quite sharp one! :)

Comment: Yup perfect and most optimized one!! What do you recommend for learning javascript from scratch with logic making too? I am nobe and got stuck on such cases. In this question this is my least attempt for my problem solving ;)

Comment: Hehe. Answering questions here. I started reading "JavaScript the Definitive Guide" in 1995/1996 so that is where I started. With Netscape 3 or so

Comment: Hahaha impressive 1995/1996 :) I will give it a shot now. Any more recommendation for 2020? :D

Comment: Yup that's right Sir. :) Thanks a lot for your time and solution. Going to accept it :)

Comment: @LearningROR Thanks - was afraid I was going to lose the accept to the earlier reduce. I only just started using reduce half a year ago and it does not come naturally to me  - so I always start with a forEach

Comment: Reduce is definitely worth putting time into :) I'm upvoting this answer too

Comment: Yups that right and reduce can be used in many places at once :) Anyways I am giving you upvote too TomaszBubała. Thanks both of you. @mplungjan is lagend here and I found him very helpful since last few years. :) Stay blessed and thanks again.

Comment: My client says, in germany week 19 starts from Monday to Sunday but when he access the website from his country ( germany ), it shows him week number 19 starting from Sunday to Saturday. I think we need to define timezone ( germany ) in our code so that whenever he will access website from germany the week number will start to work as per his expectations. In my side week 19 shows from Mon To Sun but on his side week 19 on UI shows him Sun to Sat.

Comment: I think its fixed, I will ask from client later. Also, one thing, in react, I didn't mention the locale/de.min.js in my code and in console (based on your code) its showing the german based week names. What's the magic that it automatically showing the german based week names? :D

Comment: In moment it is the locale file I added when you said German. In plan JS it is the INTL part

Comment: Stay blessed Sir, thank you very much. I will get review from client. You were so helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit messy, but I'll do my best. I used your implementation of `getWeekNumber`, provided my own dates and wrote a simple `reduce`. If there's no entry for a particular week, we add it with a count of one, otherwise we increment and that's it. Learn more about `Array.prototype.reduce` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const dates = [
  new Date('2000-01-01'),
  new Date('2000-01-25'),
  new Date('2000-02-01'),
  new Date('2000-02-02'),
  new Date('2000-02-03'),
];

const getWeekNumber = now => {
  let onejan = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  return Math.ceil((((now - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay()) / 7);
}

const result = dates.reduce((countPerWeek, date) => {
  const weekNumber = getWeekNumber(date);

  if (!countPerWeek[weekNumber]) {
    countPerWeek[weekNumber] = 1;
  } else {
    countPerWeek[weekNumber]++;
  }
 
  return countPerWeek;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: See my comments in other answer. Please! its giving wrong output.

Comment: So May started on 1st may friday and from friday(1st) to monday (3rd) its 1st week of may but 18th week of 2020).

Comment: How is it wrong? If you provide your own dates it should count them per week just like you wanted

Comment: I am sorry, let me check it ;)

Comment: Yup, I checked it with your data and it gives the results you provided in your question :) which is `18=>3, 19=>7, 20=> 7, 21=>7, 22=>7`